# Moving from typings to @types using Visual Studio & Typescript 2.0.3

Tags: visual-studio-2015, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I've tried to remove typings from my web project (Visual Studio 2015 Community) and install d.ts files via new NPM @types (typescript 2.0.3) in package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@types/angular": "^1.5.8",
    "@types/angular-cookies": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/angular-local-storage": "^0.1.33",
    "@types/angular-material": "^1.1.37",
    "@types/angular-translate": "^2.4.33",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.36"
  }
```

Visual Studio's IntelliSense worked nicely with typings before because I included typings folder in my VS project. NPM installs types into `node_modules/@types` folder. Now here is my problem. I don't really want to include anything from `node_modules` in VS project. 
`node_modules` folder should be fine to get deleted and recreated again by npm at will.
Visual Studio does not recognize the typings installed without them being included in the project!
I guess I could create a file with ///reference tags in it but then I would have to maintain this file manually when installing/removing typings.

Is there any recommended way to make VS IntelliSense work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was struggling with this same problem after making the switch to 2.0 and using the new @types convention.

I found this useful property after looking into the spec for the tsconfig.json here: http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig

"typeRoots" property of compilerOptions.

I could not get the files or include arrays to pull in my typings, but this seems to have done the trick for me.

My tsconfig.json file as an example:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope this helps someone with the same issue.

Comment: This indeed does the trick for the typescript compiler. But Visual Studio IntelliSence still complains about missing types.

Comment: Do you have typescript installed globally via "npm install -g typescript" ?

I seem to have no problems with intellisense, there must be some other global configuration that's missing.

In addition to globally installed typescript, have you run "npm install typings -g" ?

Comment: After double checking I realized that when using new @types repo the modules for Intellisense will not be available unless imported explicitly. For example for lodash I have to use `import * as _ from 'lodash'; ` I think this is the answer to my original question.

Comment: This fixed IntelliSense for me as well as the build - I hadn't been using a tsconfig file until now because the projects had their own TypeScript settings in Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

Install VS 2015 Update 3, then install TypeScript 2.0.3 tools.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using @types in Visual Studio 2015 (as of Update 3)...

First, be sure to have TypeScript v2.0.3 or higher.

Then, add typings as follows:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",

    "@types/jquery": "*",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.36"
  }
```

Then, in your TypeScript file, simply add the following...

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="jquery.lodash.d.ts" />
```

In order to see if a library type is available, check out [Type Search](http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/), powered by [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped).

References:

- MSDN Blog - TypesScript: [The Future of Declaration Files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/)
- MSDN Blog - No Time: [Angular 2 with @Types declaration files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/notime/2016/09/23/angular-2-with-types-declaration-files/)